# How to generate the 3D object below?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, regions

I am quite new to the 3D figuring in Mathematica. I wanted to know how can I generate a 3D object like this using the usual commands of Mathematica. [image]

The object is like a cone with rectangular cross-sections.

Comment: Shouldn't the bottom view show a gradient?

Comment: Yes, it should. For simplicity, I showed it with a lighter color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the future, you should try your own code first, reading docs and posting a solution for others to review and possibly improve.

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygnv9.jpg"];
shape = RegionBinarize[i, {200, 600}, .5];
Region[RegionProduct[ImageMesh[shape], Line[{{0.}, {100.}}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, sure. But in this case, I didn't know how to start. By the way, thanks for the answer. For the second line it gives me this error:
"Expecting either an image or graphics with dimensions {424,934} or a \
list of positions to specify markers instead of {200,600}"

Comment: @M.Rock try now - fixed a typo.

Comment: The problem exist. but I tried it on another pc with mathematica 11.0 and it worked. Thanks for your answer